# Consequences of reneging an internship return offer

Tags: job-offer, internship

I accepted the return offer from my internship company 'A' last month because the deadline they gave me is relatively tight. But I got another better offer from 'B' recently, this is kind of like a dream offer to me and I really want to work there. But I didn't tell B I already signed A, when they asked me I just said I have an offer deadline.

I'm afraid that if I withdraw the return offer from A, and when B calling for the background check, A would say that I'm not eligible for rehire since I withdrew an offer before, and B would also cancel my job offer as well since I'm not being honest or something.

I don't know what should I do now, is calling B and tell them about this a good idea? Or should I just politely call A and hoping they will not say bad things about me when answering the background call?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the jurisdiction? @HMY

Comment: jurisdiction? I think there's no legal restrict since it's at-will offer?

Comment: You haven't worked for A yet, why would B contact them?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere no I didn't say that..

Comment: @SethR that's my internship working experience and it would show up in my resume, i'm afraid the background check would contact them

Comment: @HMY I suggest re-working the question so that you aren't asking what you should do. Perhaps you should ask what are the professional considerations for reneging or whether or not it's possible to renegotiate with company A.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings That's for deciding different offers, my situation is I already accepted now want to renege that offer, and worry about if it'll have negative effect on the background check

Comment: This depends on the stipulations of your employment contract. Generally, in the US, you are an at-will employee which means your company or you may terminate the relationship at any time. Generally, for employment verification in the US, your internship company will only confirm the dates that you worked there and your title.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm afraid that if I withdraw the return offer from A, and when B
>   calling for the background check, A would say that I'm not eligible
>   for rehire since I withdrew an offer before

That's a very valid fear. Whenever I am called as a reference, I'm always asked if I would rehire the applicant. I won't lie when answering that question. I may politely decline to answer that question, but the caller will know what it means if I don't enthusiastically say I would rehire the candidate.

> , and B would also cancel my job offer as well since I'm not being
>   honest or something.

Well, you are demonstrating that you are willing to go back on your word. That's not exactly the same thing as not being honest. But still, some potential employers wouldn't look favorable on it.

> I don't know what should I do now, is calling B and tell them about
>   this a good idea?

Only do this is you are willing to have B cancel their offer.

> Or should I just politely call A and hoping they will not say bad
>   things about me when answering the background call?

If you are willing to reneg on your word, then I suppose this is your only viable solution. Many choose the same path.